# Distribution on different developer-Macs

Tags: ios, macos

I often work on different iMac-Systems (at Home, at Work, or on a MacBook on hollyday) with the same Apple-Developer-Account.
When I will bring the App to the store, I often got a message that on the current iMac I doesn't have my account validated to upload.

What is the best way to solve this "little" problem (I doesn't want to revoke each time), so that I can work on every system .
Can someone give me a hint.

Regards

Comment: you need to export your account from your primary machine's xcode which contains private keys in keychain and install to all other development machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your certificates for Distribution and/or development, and install them on all your systems. This way, you won't have to revoke the certificate every time. Remember to export certificate with its key. They can be exported from "Keychain"

Answer (score 0):

You export your developer profile from within Xcode and import it on a different machine.  See the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html).

As the profile is encrypted you can use something like Dropbox to make it available on all your machines.